# How does this "Multi-Way Ladder" work?

Tags: ladder

I bought a used ladder a few days ago. It's an Eagle brand "Multi-Way Ladder" that can be used as a step ladder or a short straight extension ladder. The model number is LP-711E.

Unfortunately I can't find a manual or manufacturers site for it even though it appears to still be a current model, and some of the stickers on the ladder are worn/ scratched off, so I'm not 100% sure how to use it in either configuration.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to set it up in both step ladder and extension mode? I'm hoping someone has the same ladder or the equivalent from another manufacturer and can provide pictures showing how to do this right.

Here is a picture of it in what I think is the basic stepladder configuration:

[image]

I've found the same model on several store's websites, with pictures of it in step and extension mode, but very low res so I can't tell exactly what has to slot into what to get it in and out of each mode properly. Here is an [example from Rona](https://www.rona.ca/en/eagle-multi-way-ladder-combined-t2-aluminum-7-ft-11-ft-lp-711e-8708010):

[image]

I notice the pic from Rona has two black plastic claws that appear to hold the round rungs of the upper section in extension mode while mine has that aluminum scoop looking thing that I think serves the same purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to know exactly what does what before you use this. Safety first.

Comment: the top picture is correct for step ladder configuration ... the green yokes on left section have to engage a right side rung .... slide right section upward for use on stairs .... engage one of the right side rungs into the aluminium scoop for extension ladder configuration